# Elliptic regularity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Given the problem, $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, $a$ is continuous, coercive (elliptic) and bilinear, $L$ is continuous suppose this problem has a unique solution

$$\begin{cases}
u \in V, \\
a(u,v) = L(v), \forall v \in V
\end{cases}$$

my question is about working backwards to classical solutions with elliptic regularity theorem. So by setting $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a regular, bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$. If $u$ is a solution then $u \in H^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ by elliptic regularity theorem, and we can infer that the PDE satisfied is

$$-\Delta u = f $$

is there anything to be said about the boundary here? What if $V=H^1(\Omega)$, can elliptic regularity can be used again to show $u \in L^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$? How would one find out any information about the boundary?

Comment: The problem may have many solutions if the boundary data is not fixed, however, at least for inteiror regularity, they will always have two additional derivatives more than $f$.

Comment: Can additional constraints allow us to get any boundary data. In the case of $H^1(\Omega)$ for example, if we have $a$ symmetric, the boundary $C^\infty$ etc. ?